# Crash with simple history push

Tags: cyclejs

just trying come silly stuff and playing around with Cycle.js. and running into problem. Basically I just have a button. When you click it it's suppose to navigate the location to a random hash and display it. Almost like a stupid router w/o predefined routes. Ie. routes are dynamic. Again this isn't anything practical I am just messing with some stuff and trying to learn Cycle.js. But the code below crashes after I click "Add" button. However the location is updated. If I actually just navigate to "#/asdf" it displays the correct content with "Hash: #/asdf". Not sure why the flow is crashing with error:

render-dom.js:242 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined(…)

```
import Rx from 'rx';
import Cycle from '@cycle/core';
import { div, p, button, makeDOMDriver } from '@cycle/dom';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import ranomdstring from 'randomstring';

const history = createHashHistory({ queryKey: false });

function CreateButton({ DOM }) {
  const create$ = DOM.select('.create-button').events('click')
    .map(() => {
      return ranomdstring.generate(10);
    }).startWith(null);

  const vtree$ = create$.map(rs => rs ?
    history.push(`/${rs}`) :
    button('.create-button .btn .btn-default', 'Add')
  );

  return { DOM: vtree$ };
}

function main(sources) {
  const hash = location.hash;
  const DOM = sources.DOM;

  const vtree$ = hash ?
    Rx.Observable.of(
      div([
        p(`Hash: ${hash}`)
      ])
    ) :
    CreateButton({ DOM }).DOM;

  return {
    DOM: vtree$
  };
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#main-container')
});
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your function `CreateButton` you are mapping your clicks to `history.push()` instead of mapping it to a vtree which causes the **error**:

```js
function CreateButton({ DOM }) {
  ...
  const vtree$ = create$.map(rs => rs
    ? history.push(`/${rs}`) // <-- not a vtree
    : button('.create-button .btn .btn-default', 'Add')
  );
  ...
}
```

Instead you could **use the do operator** to perform the hashchange:

```js
function CreateButton({ DOM }) {
  const create$ = 
    ...
    .do(history.push(`/${rs}`)); // <-- here

  const vtree$ = Observable.of(
    button('.create-button .btn .btn-default', 'Add')
  );
  ...
}
```

However in functional programming **you should not perform side effects on you app logic**, every function must remain [pure](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976#.evhhl4kqr). Instead, all side effects should be handled by drivers. To learn more take a look at the [drivers section on Cycle's documentation](http://cycle.js.org/drivers.html)

To see a working driver jump at the end of the message.

---

Moreover on your `main` function you were not using streams to render your vtree. It would have not been reactive to locationHash changes because `vtree$ = hash ? ... : ...` is only evaluated once on app bootstrapping (when the main function is evaluated and "wires" every streams together).

An improvement will be to declare your `main`'s vtree$ as following while keeping the same logic:

```js
const vtree$ = hash$.map((hash) => hash ? ... : ...)
```

---

Here is a complete solution with a small locationHash driver:

```js
import Rx from 'rx';
import Cycle from '@cycle/core';
import { div, p, button, makeDOMDriver } from '@cycle/dom';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import randomstring from 'randomstring';


function makeLocationHashDriver (params) {
  const history = createHashHistory(params);

  return (routeChange$) => {
    routeChange$
      .filter(hash => {
        const currentHash = location.hash.replace(/^#?\//g, '')
        return hash && hash !== currentHash
      })
      .subscribe(hash => history.push(`/${hash}`));

    return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'hashchange')
      .startWith({})
      .map(_ => location.hash);
  }
}

function CreateButton({ DOM }) {
  const create$ = DOM.select('.create-button').events('click')
    .map(() => randomstring.generate(10))
    .startWith(null);

  const vtree$ = Rx.Observable.of(
    button('.create-button .btn .btn-default', 'Add')
  );

  return { DOM: vtree$, routeChange$: create$ };
}

function main({ DOM, hash }) {
  const button = CreateButton({ DOM })
  const vtree$ = hash.map(hash => hash
    ? Rx.Observable.of(
        div([
          p(`Hash: ${hash}`)
        ])
      )
    : button.DOM
  )

  return {
    DOM: vtree$,
    hash: button.routeChange$
  };
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#main-container'),
  hash: makeLocationHashDriver({ queryKey: false })
});
```

PS: there is a typo in your `randomstring` function name, I fixed it in my example.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Should have figured it out. Thanks help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I would further suggest using @cycle/history to do your route changing
(Only showing relevant parts)

```
import {makeHistoryDriver} from '@cycle/history'
import {createHashHistory} from 'history'

function main(sources) {
  ...
  return {history: Rx.Observable.just('/some/route') } // a stream of urls
}

const history = createHashHistory({ queryKey: false })
Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#main-container'),
  history: makeHistoryDriver(history),
})
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback. Sorry I feel really dumb, but I couldn't get it working with @cycle/history; I tried different things and read the documentation. How do I connect the history driver with the button's change events? Am I suppose to combine the two streams?

Comment: Hmm I think I finally figured it out thanks for the help.